# Setup vhost ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am trying to setup a vhost in ubuntu, my file is like

```
  /var/www/vhost/domain1.com/app
  /var/www/vhost/domain1.com/public
  /var/www/vhost/domain2.com/app
  /var/www/vhost/domain2.com/public
```

the vhost in `/etc/apache2/site-avalable/domain1.com.conf` is :

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
  ServerName  domain1.com
  ServerAlias *.domain1.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/public
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/log/access.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

---

problem

the vhost folder and all the files after that (the children) are accessible in the web browser. I know I have to put some sort of htaccess but i don't know how and where I have to put it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use apache 2.4 and you develop on a local machine:

1. Create a new configuration file for your website:

   ```
   $ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain1.com.conf
   ```
2. Edit the file like so:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerName domain1.com
       ServerAlias *.domain1.com

       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/domain1.com/public

       ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/log/error.log
       CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/log/access.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Enable the website

   ```
   $ sudo a2ensite domain1.com
   ```
4. Restart apache

   ```
   $ sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
5. Add the following line to your /etc/hosts file

   ```
   127.0.1.1      domain1.com
   ```

Now it should work, go to http://domain1.com and check it out.